# On Apache 2.4, how can I disable the php7 module?

Tags: apache-2.4, php7

I want to disable the php7 module.

```
apache2 -M | grep php
```

returns:

> php7_module (shared)

However, these commands fail:

```
a2dismod php7
a2dismod php7_module
```

They both return a message specifying that the module doesn't exist.

How can I sweet-talk Apache into recognizing that the modules exist, are loaded and running? And then to unload them?

Answer (score 1):

Depends a little on the environment, but try this command or adapt for your filesystem.

```
ls /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/php*.load
```

Then use a2dismod with the name shown excluding the .load  extension

On my machine would be

```
a2dismod php7.0
```